# Maven Embedded Glassfish Plugin - how to set the temporary directory?

Tags: maven-2, glassfish, maven-plugin, glassfish-3, glassfish-embedded

I am using the Maven Embedded Glassfish Plugin and it works great, but unfortunately it creates a temporary directory in my main project directory.  I would like it to use target so that every time I clean the project, the embedded directory also gets wiped.

Is there a setting for that?

Walter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** According to the OP, the needed parameter is actually `instanceRoot`, not `installRoot`.

I think that you can use the <strike>`installRoot`</strike> [`instanceRoot`](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/821-1208/gjkxo?a=view)  parameter for this. Set it to the `target` directory:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <instanceRoot>${project.build.directory}</instanceRoot>
    <goalPrefix>glassfish</goalPrefix>
    <app>target/test.war</app>
    <port>8080</port>
    <contextRoot>test</contextRoot>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>install</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>run</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't change the gfembed temp directory.  I am still looking to change that to target.



Walter

Comment: instanceRoot was the setting I needed.

Comment: @Walter Wasn't 100% sure about the parameter (I guess I misunderstood the bottom note of [Installation Root Directory](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/821-1208/gikqf?a=view)). Thanks for the feedback, I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the correct way to do this is to use the [infuriatingly and partially undocumented](http://www.java.net/node/699975?force=209) `glassfish.embedded.tmpdir` `System` property, and eliminate all usage of the `BootstrapProperties#setInstallRoot(String)` or `BootstrapProperties#setInstanceRoot(String)` methods.